# How do I write a CosmosDBTrigger that updates the same document that was changed?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I need to write a CosmosDBTrigger that updates the document that was changed. I see documentation about an output document, which seems to cover the case where you are just writing a new document into CosmosDB. But, what about updating the same document that was changed?

```
 [FunctionName("MyFunctionName")]
 public static async Task RunAsync(
     [CosmosDBTrigger(
         databaseName: "MyDatabase",
         collectionName: "Orders",
         ConnectionStringSetting = "databaseConnection",
         MaxItemsPerInvocation = 1,
         CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true,
         LeaseDatabaseName = "TriggerLeases",
         LeaseCollectionName = "TriggerLeases",
         LeaseCollectionPrefix = "MyFunctionPrefix")]IReadOnlyList<Document> input,
     [CosmosDB(
         databaseName: "MyDatabase",
         collectionName: "Orders",
         ConnectionStringSetting = "databaseConnection", 
         Id = "{Id}")] MyCustomOrderObject output,
     ILogger log)
 {
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the output binding is to [overwrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=csharp#usage) if matching an existing item by ID:

> When you specify the ID of an existing document, it gets overwritten
> by the new output document.

Of course with this scenario we need to prevent infinite loops that would occur if we always update the item that triggered, leading to another trigger/update, etc and forever.

Another more involved approach with more control is to use [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) to use a proper repository/service class with the full Cosmos SDK, in lieu of an output binding. So you receive the changed item from trigger and hand it to your own service to separately make any resulting changes. This may be preferable if you already have an abstraction in your app to pull in and use for consistency.

Comment: Okay sure, but how can I get the CosmosDBTrigger parameters such as databaseName and collectionName and ConnectionStringSetting in my Startup.Configure? If I cannot get those then I have to duplicate the config values, which feels wrong.

Comment: The IFunctionsHostBuilder can be used to get the configuration through its services collection. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings

Comment: I'm getting an error "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'mytype' while attempting to activate 'MyFunction'".

Comment: There seems to be all sorts of problems with async. Of course, async is built into the Cosmos Library. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4939

Comment: You have add an assembly attribute to tell it to use the FunctionStartup. Luckily I found someone this article that mentions it the very end: https://www.code4it.dev/blog/azure-functions-startup-class